# Using 210 V DC to a 220 V AC heater: is it going to work?

Tags: solar-energy, arc

I'm considering building an off-grid solar system piece by piece. I can afford a couple of solar panels, after that an inverter, and finally batteries. I was thinking about finding a practical application for the solar panels until I can afford the other components.

The one I thought was to connect them in series to provide 210 v DC @ 10A and connect that to a simple AC heater element (without a fan). Now I understand that this is not the most efficient way to heat up a house, neither is it a good idea to play around with 210 V DC. So let's not focus on those two things.

The two questions: I'm curious about if this will work without any MPPT controller. The power for the heater is 2000 W at 220 V AC.

And what about arcs? is it possible to see arcs at this DC voltage?

The panels are 7 x 24 V with ~30 V peak working voltage.

Finishing up, can you suggest any other useful applications of just solar panels without batteries or AC inverter (hydrogen doesn't seem interesting to me).

Comment: You can direct connect solar to a variable frequency drive (VFD) to run anything that runs on induction motors. A pool pump. A well pump. Air conditioning compressor. No batteries. You probably want to supply at least 300 VDC to the VFD, though.

Comment: Without an MPP controller, you may not get maximum power. But you will still possibly get lots of power. You will want to try to match the resistance of the heating element to the Vmpp and Impp of the solar panel. The closer you are to that point, the more power you will get. If you put panels in series, add the Vmpp's and keep Impp the same as one panel. If you put panels in parallel, add the Impp's and keep Vmpp same as one panel.

Comment: Simply choosing a load resistor = Vmpp/Impp (from the label on the panels) will get max power at standard illumination. You'll lose a few % at any other illumination but it's close enough.

Comment: I like the VFD idea. I didn't though of that even I have one for my cnc mill. My understanding is that they convert the AC to DC and then they make it AC again so if I disconnect the AC circuit and feed DC directly it would work? Since the computer psu also convert from AC to DC I think I will try that as well.

Comment: Some VFD's can run on DC. I found some notes published by Hitatchi explaining how to run their VFD's on DC. There could be some issues with inrush current if you are not careful. But for solar I don't think this will be too much of a problem (since solar is inherently current limited). https://www.hitachi.us/supportingdocs/forbus/inverters/Support/AN091802-1%20Rev%20A_Powering_from_DC_supply.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It should work for a simple resistive heater element no worries. It will be trying to draw almost 10A. Your panels may struggle to provide this (a 200w panel at 30v will be producing ~ 6.6A). As for arcing the dielectric strength of air is ~10000v/cm so 300V can arc about 0.03cm.
For just panels alone you could use them to heat a hot water cylinder to have a supply of hot water on hand. Or perhaps some sort of profitable electrolysis (other than hydrogen i guess)

Comment: You are underestimating the problems associated with arcing. The arcing happens when you try to interrupt the current. It can be challenging to turn off a 200-300 V DC circuit. The switches or fuses or breakers must be designed with this in mind.

Comment: great point on the switch arcing, wouldn't a simple 240v household rated switch handle this?

Comment: No. You need a DC rated switch. You can search for videos online that show what happens. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zez2r1RPpWY.  AC circuit breakers may only last a few cycles if they interrupt a DC overload.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=csMQ9A-4Pws

Comment: There are some higher voltage AC/DC rated disconnects, but they are not ordinary household switches.

Comment: thank you @mkeith for your insides. I received the first two panel today. They provided me with 70v DC with out a load and the acr was unexpectably strong for such low voltage. I will have to find solar DC switch.